# Service upstart is not working properly. I don't know why?

Tags: django, deployment, service, gunicorn, upstart

I am deploying the Django project with gunicorn and nginx.
I followed to the tutorial the link [http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn](http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/)

The file service named 'testgunicorn':

```
description "Django XXXXXXXXX"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
respawn limit 10 5
exec /home/htk/workspace/testproject/envs/run.sh
```

But when I run the service : `service testgunicorn start`
It logged: `testgunicorn start/running, process 14259`
But when I check the status: `service testgunicron status`
It logged : `testgunicorn stop/waiting`

The content of file 'run.sh'

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
LOGFILE=/home/my-user/workspace/testproject/testproject.log
NUM_WORKERS=2

# user/group to run as
USER=my-user
GROUP=my-group
cd /home/htk/workspace/testproject
source envs/bin/activate
exec python2.7 manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8090 -w $NUM_WORKERS \
--user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug \
--log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE
```

The file 'run.sh' , I checked it ran ok.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please update the question with the contents of run.sh